# How can I run a Graphql query in a Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, rails-console

I have a Graphql query working in Graphiql:

```
query MyConfigurationType {
  myConfiguration {
    number
    expirationDate
  }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "myConfiguration": {
      "number": 1,
      "expirationDate": "2022/10/04"
    }
  }
}
```

But I need to actually use that result in my app therefore I want to be able to run it in my rails console. There doesn't seem to be much info about this.

How would one go about executing a Graphql query in the Rails console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some [documentation](https://graphql-ruby.org/queries/executing_queries) the best I could manage to do was, in the Rails console do:

```
query_string = "query MyConfigurationType {
  myConfiguration {
    number
    expirationDate
  }
}"
```

and the run

```
result = MySchema.execute(query_string)
```

Which has a result of

```
=> #<GraphQL::Query::Result @query=... @to_h={"data"=>{"myConfiguration"=>{"number"=>1, "expirationDate"=>"2022/10/04"}}}>
```

Therefore one can now do

```
[1] pry(main)> result['data']
=> {"myConfiguration"=>{"number"=1, "expirationDate"=>"2022/10/04"}}
```